# Вопрос по соединению данных на web-странице

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных

Существуют 3 страницы, которые привязаны к одной бд.
В бд 2 таблицы, первая с айди элемента и с элементом,
вторая с айди связи, айди родителя, родитель, айди дочери, дочь.

1 страница с элементами, 2 со связями и 3 страница с выводом связи на экран.
Выполнена связь с бд, вся информация с базы данных.

Выполнено через функцию mysql concat.
В коде это всего одна строчка

```
$sql = "SELECT CONCAT (parent,' - ', subsidiary) AS elements1, id FROM link";
```

Вопрос: Как или с помощью чего можно сделать вывод не двух элементов бд, а полоностью последовательности в строчку?

Допустим не:
Машина-Десятка
Цвет-Зелёный
А, Машина-Десятка-Цвет-Зелёный.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А в чем проблема выбрать из базы несколько строк, а потом уже в скрипте их объединить в одну как вам надо?

Comment: Будет огромная база данных, где данные постоянно будут обновляться и каким скриптом это можно реализовать?, Что бы не лезть постоянно в бд и код, а делать это на странице.

Comment: Структура данных, которую вы описали, называется - несбалансированным деревом и у вас храниться по паттерну material path. В таком случае, вам можно сделать один запрос с указанием глубины выборки, вроде ищем корневой элемент с parent_id = null, далее join на дочку, т.к. у вас есть child_id, на сколько понимаю, если нет, то добавть в вашу структу указание depth и начинайте с дочки и идите до самого корневого элемента, т.к. parent_id у вас точно имеется.

Comment: Сам скрипт будет формировать запрос, сколько join-ов вам нужно, откуда начать и т.п., однако, это можно сделать и с помощью СУРБД через единственный запрос. Можно что-то почерпнуть здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26084930/self-join-to-get-maximum-number-of-depth-in-mysql/26084999.